# How to save values in database using Sqlite?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to do a tracker application in wp8. I want to save the values in database using Sqlite. All the values r working (time, distance and pace). After pressing Stop button, I want the values to be posted in a table view using Sqlite as u can see in the second screen. Any good suggestions or links are appreciated. Thank u.

[image]

Comment: what is pace here, it's a time in min and sec or hour and min please clear it fast

Comment: pace = minutes / distance

Comment: as I answered, you can change total time in minutes and divide it by distance and then store total minutes in database

Answer (score 1):

Try this [nokia developer site here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone).

Gives you a small tutorial how to use sqlite on windows phones.

This piece of code gives you the answer?

```
 private void Insert_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new task.
            Task task = new Task()
            {
                Title = TitleField.Text,
                Text = TextField.Text,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            /// Insert the new task in the Task table.
            dbConn.Insert(task);
            /// Retrieve the task list from the database.
            List<Task> retrievedTasks = dbConn.Table<Task>().ToList<Task>();
            /// Clear the list box that will show all the tasks.
            TaskListBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var t in retrievedTasks)
            {
                TaskListBox.Items.Add(t);
            }
        }
```

hm, i see this is a retrieval piece of code. Maybee this [site helps you further](http://jesseliberty.com/2013/03/14/windows-8-storing-data-with-sqlite/).

The following example is an insert:

```
public void Initialize()
{
   using ( var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection( _dbPath ) )
   {
      db.CreateTable<Customer>();

      //Note: This is a simplistic initialization scenario
      if ( db.ExecuteScalar<int>( 
             "select count(1) from Customer" ) == 0 )
      {

         db.RunInTransaction( () =>
         {
            db.Insert( new Customer() { 
               FirstName = "Jon", LastName = "Galloway" } );
            db.Insert( new Customer() { 
               FirstName = "Jesse", LastName = "Liberty" } );
         } );
      }
      else
      {
         Load();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried the nokia site link which u gav but it didn't work. got stuck in the middle. Anyway i completed this task using SQLiteWinRTPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your table is.

```
    public class HistoryTable
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public double pace { get; set; }
        public double distance { get; set; }
    }
```

Insert values using this statement.

```
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    double pace = 16;
    double distance = 4;
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.sqlite"));
    conn.Execute("Insert into HistoryTable values(?,?,?,?)", date, time, pace, distance);
```

Fetch your data as below statement, I'm assuming that you know how to bind the data in [listbox](/questions/tagged/listbox) if there is need. I'm taking the values in textbox.

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.sqlite"));
    var result = conn.Table<HistoryTable>();
    foreach (var val in result)
    {
        TimeSpan pace = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(val.pace);
        TextBoxDate.Text = val.date;
        TextBoxTime.Text = val.time;
        TextBoxPace.Text = pace.Minutes + ":" + pace.Seconds;
        TextBoxDistance.Text = val.distance + " Km";
    }
```

The reason why I used Pace as double because I can use this double value as total minutes and can be changed as [timespan](/questions/tagged/timespan)(in minutes and seconds). For any other queries you can ask any time.
To get exactly the same format as you ask in your question you should use like this also.

```
    string date = string.Format("{0:00}.{1:00}.{2:00}", DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Year);
    string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    double pace = 16.5;
    double distance = 4;
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.sqlite"));
    conn.Execute("Insert into HistoryTable values(?,?,?,?)", date, time, pace, distance);
```

At the time of fetching info, please change the above steps by this.

```
    TextBoxDistance.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}Km", val.distance);
```

Comment: @RajVeer Thank you raj for improving my answer