# How to apply Isolated Storage to the values in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to apply Isolated Storage to the textBlocks in the following Program. U can understand clearly what I am trying to do is, by seeing these images in this link" [How to save values in database using Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406368/how-to-save-values-in-database-using-sqlite/17407580?noredirect=1#17407580)   "I need date(today's date - which is not included in the code), time(TimeLabel.Text), pace(paceLabel.Text), distance(distanceLabel.Text) to be in Isolated Storage from the below program to post them in listbox. Any links which can give me good idea to store values in IsolatedStorage(brief answer) to be posted in Listbox are also accepted and appreciated. Thank u in advance.

```
//location tracker
public partial class Mog : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
         //   private Geo
          //  _watcher = new Geolocator(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
          private GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
            private MapPolyline _line;
            private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            private long _startTime;   
    public Mog()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            _line = new MapPolyline();
            _line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
            _line.StrokeThickness = 5;
            Map.MapElements.Add(_line);

            _watcher.Start();

            _timer.Start();
            _startTime = System.Environment.TickCount;

            _watcher.PositionChanged += Watcher_PositionChanged;

            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        } 


private double _kilometres;
        private double calories;      
        private long _previousPositionChangeTick;

private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            //IsolatedStorageSettings milli = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            var coord = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);

            if (_line.Path.Count > 0)
            {
                var calories = caloriesLabel.Text;

                var previousPoint = _line.Path.Last();
                var distance = coord.GetDistanceTo(previousPoint);
                var millisPerKilometer = (1000.0 / distance) * (System.Environment.TickCount - _previousPositionChangeTick);
                _kilometres += distance / 1000.0;               
                paceLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisPerKilometer).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                distanceLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f2} km", _kilometres);
                caloriesLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f0}", _kilometres * 65);
                PositionHandler handler = new PositionHandler();
                var heading = handler.CalculateBearing(new Position(previousPoint), new Position(coord));
                Map.SetView(coord, Map.ZoomLevel, heading, MapAnimationKind.Parabolic);
            }
else
      {
        Map.Center = coord;
      }

      _line.Path.Add(coord);
      _previousPositionChangeTick = System.Environment.TickCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: So do you want the values stored in IsoStorage or Sqlite?

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot can u pls help me to place this values in IsolatedStorage?

Comment: you want to store the whole list or just the last values ??

Comment: only the values which i have asked above. that is, when i press stop - all the four values should be stored into the isolated storage and get posted into the ListBox. If u can see the link i've attached to this question, u will get clear understanding. hope so. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to store collections like this is to serialize the collection into json and save a file. You can use Json.Net for this. You would need to create a collection of objects to store the values.

```
public class RunMarker
{
    public double Kilometers { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Pace { get; set; }
    public double Calories { get; set; }
}
```

When the position changes you would set values on this and add it to a collection.

```
private void Watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    // add actual values
    _markers.Add(new RunMarker { Kilometers = 0, Pace = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Calories = 50 });
}
```

Then when you want to save it you serialize to Json and save a file in IsolatedStorage

```
const string MarkerFileName = "RunMarker.json";

var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (storage.FileExists(MarkerFileName)) storage.DeleteFile(MarkerFileName);

using (var fileStream = storage.CreateFile(MarkerFileName))
{
    //Write the data
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_markers);
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps